# Авторизация, куки, firefox

Tags: php, cookie, firefox

В данный момент, генерирую уникальный ключ и сохраняю его в куках браузера у пользователя.

Заметил, что firefox не дает сохранить повторно куку если ранее ее срок истек.
То есть пользователь уже не сможет авторизоваться.

Вопрос, кто как реализовал у себя авторизацию. Как лучше, возможно я что та не так делаю как все...

Comment: уникальным ключом обычно является идентификатор сессии и пхп сам за него отвечает при старте сессии.

Comment: То есть не стоит придумывать ключ, просто взять ключ сессии и все? По умолчанию, как долго храниться сессия, то есть ключ сессии? Возможно ли увеличить срок, скажем до месяца?

Comment: вам бы начать со чтения документации или книжек. там и про сессии найдется и про время хранения сессионных кук будет

Comment: Чем черевато, если срок хранения увеличить с 24минут на 30 дней?

Comment: увеличением объема дискового пространства необходимого для хранения сессионных данных